# ML.Net Image classification Error: Invalid argument: input must be 4-dimensional[224,224,3]

Tags: ml.net

I am getting this error, I am using ML.Net 1.5.2. I am having no issues with ML.Net 0.10.0, but I recently upgraded.

```
2020-10-06 11:51:40.611074: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops_fused_impl.h:716 : Invalid argument: input must be 4-dimensional[224,224,3]
input must be 4-dimensional[224,224,3]
         [[{{node conv2d0}}]]
```

My pipeline is below,

```
var pipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: LabelTokey, inputColumnName: "Label")
                            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(ImageReal, trainImagesFolder, nameof(ImageNetData.ImagePath)))
                            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: ImageReal, imageWidth: ImageNetSettings.imageWidth, imageHeight: ImageNetSettings.imageHeight, inputColumnName: ImageReal))
                            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "input", inputColumnName: ImageReal, interleavePixelColors: ImageNetSettings.channelsLast, offsetImage: ImageNetSettings.mean))
                            .Append(_mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(_settings.InceptionPath)
                                  .ScoreTensorFlowModel(outputColumnNames: new[] { "softmax2_pre_activation" }, inputColumnNames: new[] { "input" }))
                            .Append(_mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LbfgsMaximumEntropy(labelColumnName: LabelTokey, featureColumnName: "softmax2_pre_activation"))
                            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue(PredictedLabelValue, "PredictedLabel"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I need to set `addBatchDimensionInput = true` in `ScoreTensorFlowModel`